# how to integrate git running on windows with jenkins running on ubuntu server?Do we need to use SSH

Tags: git, jenkins

Do we need to use SSH or provide the path of git(windows) in jenkins server.

Can someone please provide steps to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but let's assume you have a central git repository that you push to.

When configuring a Jenkins job, in the **Source Code Management** section select `git`.

The *Repository URL* is the URL you would use to clone the repo (e.g. `git@example.com/myrepo`). If you require permission to access your repo, then you will need to add credentials to allow the server to do this. Typically this is through ssh keys.

Does this answer your question?